# Is Ubuntu unstable or is it just my computer?

Tags: dual-boot, login, distro-recommendation

Three days ago, Ubuntu crashed (not responding), and I typed  <kbd>ALT</kbd>  +  <kbd>Print</kbd>  +  <kbd>Reisub</kbd> , it restarted as usual, but displayed a `System is running in low-graphics mode` message.

When I type my login and password in the terminal, a message blinks (so fast that I couldn't read it) and then it asks me to type in the login and password again.

I formatted my computer using Windows 7, and now as I run it, it is very slow. Ubuntu was far faster than, even though it is not as stable.

Anyway, is there a solution to use Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro), and prevent these system crashes and low-graphics messages from reappearing?

I really love Linux, but apparently it's unstable on my machine. What about the other distros?

Comment: How old is the computer?  Several years?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: I bought it 2 years ago (2013), it's an aspire 5732Z

Comment: @Pilot6 Ubuntu version is 14.04

Comment: What is the video adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 apparently it's WDDM

Comment: What is WDDM???

Comment: @Pilot6 When I check my graphics card it shows : " Express Mobile Intel(R) 45 (Microsoft Corporation WDDM)

Comment: @Pilot6 Apparently, windows 7 doesn't detect my graphics card :(

Comment: @SmootQ it's Intel Integrated Graphics. WDDM is the type of driver (it can support Aero). Since you have an Acer, I'm going to say there is a problem with your computer. My Acer Aspire killed itself after about 3 years. During its lifetime, though, it just got worse and worse, to the point where it would freeze up and crash every 10 minutes, no matter what OS was on it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 well, I guess I have no choice, but wait for other 2 years to say Goodbye to this computer :D

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? It seems like a hardware fail issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an Acer and had to change the hard disk after a couple of years.

Try running a `smartctl` test on the drive and see what it reports. Check out:

- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gsmartcontrol/ for the graphical version, (that seems to be for natty),
- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smartmontools/ for the command line version.

If the hard disk is messed up, things won't work well regardless of the OS. Changing the hard disk in my Acer Aspire, was very simple but I can't speak for your one. You need to check it first though.

Comment: Thank you so much for this precious answer, I'll check it out for sure.

Comment: Good man!  An edit and an upvote! (Oh, and kids nowadays don't call them OpSys any more: just OS...)  **;-)**

Comment: This way of adding comments and making changes after the event is new to me... or maybe it's old and I've forgotten it. One or the other :D